# Is there bigger weights already available for Yolov4?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I want to detect more objects than coco dataset which detects only 80 objects , I want to detect as many as possible actions also like hugging ,swimming.....etc.

I don't care about the **size** and I do **not** want to train myself ... So is there a dataset(weights) big enough already available that I can download and use or I do have to train and label for yolo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/visualizer/index.html?set=valtest&type=detection&c=%2Fm%2F03ssj5) a very huge dataset with bounding boxes!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to classify is represented as Action Recognition. Here [1] is a good repo that lists a lot of out-of-the-box models for this task.

---

An explanation: Models (like YOLO) contain two main blocks: feature extraction (CNN stuff) and classification (linear layers). When training from scratch, both feature extraction and classification will be trained from scratch. It is easy to train classification to what you want, but it is hard to train the feature extraction part (as it takes a lot of time). Hence, we typically use pre-trained models on generalized datasets (like YOLO is trained on COCO), so our feature extraction part starts from a somewhat good generalized place. Later, we replace the classification part will our own to be trained from scratch for our task.

TL;DR, you can use a pre-trained YOLO model on COCO for your task by replacing the last linear layers to classify what you want. Here are some resources for different frameworks [2, 3].

Here [4] is a simple walkthrough of how to do this.

- [1] https://github.com/jinwchoi/awesome-action-recognition/blob/master/README.md#action-recognition-and-video-understanding
- [2] TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning
- [3] PyTorch: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html
- [4] https://blog.roboflow.com/training-yolov4-on-a-custom-dataset/